# How to get div text also with it's input's values

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to obtain the text inside a given div, with also the input's values as text.

```
<div id="example">This is a <input type="text" value="right"/> test.</div>
```

If I just try to get text like this with jQuery :

```
$("#example").text();
```

The result would be `This is a test.` and I'd want : `This is a right test.`
The number of input would be unknow. As well as the order of the elements...

EDIT : 
I finally resolved my own problem :

```
var finalText="";
   $("#example").contents().filter(function() {
        if(this.nodeType==3){ finalText =finalText+ this.nodeValue;}
        else if(this.nodeName=="INPUT"){ finalText=finalText+this.value;}
           return finalText
    })
```

[The living example](http://jsfiddle.net/jDdXG/)

But [@Jonathan Lonowski answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826685/how-to-get-div-text-also-with-its-inputs-values/7826758#7826758) is more clear and simpler than mine !

Comment: You'll have to do some parsing.  Use $('#example').html().  Then parse out the HTML tags, but for each HTML tag check for a value attribute and capture it's value (of the value attribute).  It's the only way sir!  Maybe someone will graciously write the code for you in an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try cloning so you can `replaceWith` the inputs with their values. Then grab the text as you were:

```
var clone = $('#example').clone();

clone.find(':input').replaceWith(function () {
    return $(this).val();
});

alert(clone.text());
```

Comment: I like this one... shame on me I've seen it before without understanding it properly...

Comment: Nice one! one tiny change do clone.find('input:text')

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick plugin that will do this for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $.fn.extend({
        getContentText: function() {
          var t = '';
          this.contents().each(function(i,c) {
              var method = $(c).is("input") ? "val" : "text";
              t += $(c)[method]();
          });
          return t;
        }
    });

    alert($("#example").getContentText());

});
```

Try it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/wQpHM/

Answer (score 1):

You can loop though all children of the `<div>` and replace then with their values.  Something like this:

```
$.fn.allText = function(){
    var $this = this.clone();
    $this.children().each(function(){
        $(this, $this).replaceWith(this.value);
    });
    return $this.text();
};

alert($('#example').allText());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4mGmH/

Answer (score 0):

Using innerText

```
document.getElementbyId('example').innerText;
```

To get HTML tags:-

```
document.getElementbyId('example').innerHTML;
```

Refer this URL [element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3aelement.innerHTML)

Comment: OP wants the text not the HTML

Answer (score 0):

get html and strip html tags

```
$('#example')[0].innerHTML.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '').replace(/(\s+)/g, ' ')
```

Comment: The OP wants the inputs to replaced with their values, not removed.